# How do I enable a kernel module on startup?

Tags: debian, command-line, ndiswrappers

I need to run the same command every time I boot.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon.

I have added a startup application with the command under preferences "startup applications".

However the command does not run although it runs and works perfectly when I run it myself.

**Details**

The command is:

```
echo 'adminpassword' | sudo -S modprobe -v ndiswrapper
```

For some reason I need to run that every time I boot or ndiswrapper will forget I installed a windows wifi driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run a program. You just need to configure your system to load the ndiswrapper module at startup.

For that you edit the file /etc/modules with the command:

```
sudo vi /etc/modules
```

And append to the end of it the line:

ndiswrapper

The file /etc/modules configures which loadable modules are automatically loaded.

For more details please read:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules

Comment: So this works and does solve my problem. I still don't get why the startup command was not run, can someone explain that for the sake of my understanding and answering the original question?

Comment: starting applications is for applications that boot up in the desk, like opening firefox automatically when you boot. If you wanted to run the command as it was (is), you would had to place "modprobe -v ndiswrapper" in /etc/rc.local. You would not need the sudo, because it would be run as root. I suspect also that running applications probably does not honor the pipe "|" and would break the instruction anyway, but without testing, I cannot say it with a 100% certitude. And it is not a matter of "working for you", it a matter of doing it the standard way. Cheers